# Is there documentation or example on handling the posted "_search" and "filters" values server-side and building database query?

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-php

Is there an example or documentation on handling the posted "_search" and "filters" data and using it to query the database for result?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

The value `_search` is just boolean. If `_search` is `true` then one should filter the data using `filters` parameter which format described in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching#options).

One can use `prmNames` [option](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) to rename `_search`. For example `prmNames: { search: null, nd: null }` remove unneeded parameters `_search` and `nd` and another example `prmNames: { search: "isSearching" }` rename default `_search` parameter to `isSearching`.

The **handling** of the posted `filters` parameter depends on many implementation details which you use. You used both [jqgrid-asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jqgrid-asp.net/info) and [jqgrid-php](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jqgrid-php/info) tags of *commercial* products developed based on free open source jqGrid. I can't help you at all in the case because I don't know the products. Additionally I find very strange that you included PHP and ASP.NET as tags. The implementation can be *completely different* in both cases. Event if ASP.NET is your main platform then the *database access* which you use is the most important aspect of the implementation. Three typical options: Entity Framework, LINQ to SQL and `SQLCommand` with `SqlDataReader` need *absolutely different* implementation of dynamic filtering.

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5501644/315935) provide an implementation example in case of usage Entity Framework. The most advantage of usage Entity Framework is the possibility to use [ObjectQuery.Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338811%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) with *string* parameter. In the way one can construct *string* with parameters from `filters` which should be used in `WHERE` part of SQL statement. You can use mostly the same approach to build `SQLCommand` command with parameters.

LINQ to SQL on the other side don't have the possibility and one have to use more sophisticated approach like [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb737920#dynwhere) or to use some libraries (like [this one](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)).

**What I would really recommend you is to consider to use `loadonce: true`**. If the dataset which you need display in the grid contains some hundred (or even a thousand) of rows then it could be more effective to return **all the data** to jqGrid (the data should be just correctly sorted) and use `loadonce: true` to implement *local* filtering and paging of data. It can simplify your server code and the grid could be even more responsible from the users point of view because JavaScript engine is now quickly enough and local filtering by jqGrid could be more quickly as sending request to the server and usage of server side filtering.

Comment: We don't want to use "loadonce: true" anymore.  We're found it to cause more problems than it is worth (when we kept adding, hacking or customizing JQuery scripts).  We decided to let the back-end webserver do the heavy works instead.  The disadvantage with Javascript is it's a runtime environment, so we're out of luck on lack of reliable Javascript compiler.  We noticed Tony is not very active on maintaining or merging people's patches to jqGrid GitHub source code.  So we decided we're better off let the back-end webserver do the work & less headache for us.  We can't wait forever.  :-(

Comment: Okay, we'll figure it out on writing sql server scripts on our own.  Thanks for trying.